# Generating PDF's from form responses with a template.

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf-generation, google-forms

I'm currently using Form Publisher add in to make PDF's from the form responses with my required template but it is allowing me to generate only 100 files in a month. I have requirement with minimum of 500 files in month and I cannot afford premium license purchase for Form Publisher. Please help me with the basic script to generate PDF's based on form response data with my desired template.

I will share the template and sample sheet if it can be done.

Regards
Gopikrishna

Answer (score 0):

What tools are available for your usage? If you use [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), there is a `fill_form` command that can take a PDF & FDF/XFDF data, and combine the two.

Comment: Thank you for responding Robbat!! Actually i did't have such tool and really don't how this tool will link google form responses to a word template which would be save as PDF. I'm really looking for a script where we can automate with google appscript rather than using third-party tools.

Answer (score -1):

This snippet creates a PDF file using a Google Doc template and the values in a Google Spreadsheet. Just past it into the script editor of the GSheet you are using.

```
// Replace this with ID of your template document.
var TEMPLATE_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

// var TEMPLATE_ID = '1wtGEp27HNEVwImeh2as7bRNw-tO4HkwPGcAsTrSNTPc' // Demo template

// You can specify a name for the new PDF file here, or leave empty to use the 
// name of the template.
var PDF_FILE_NAME = ''

/**
 * Eventhandler for spreadsheet opening - add a menu.
 */

function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Create PDF')
    .addItem('Create PDF', 'createPdf')
    .addToUi()

} // onOpen()

/**  
 * Take the fields from the active row in the active sheet
 * and, using a Google Doc template, create a PDF doc with these
 * fields replacing the keys in the template. The keys are identified
 * by having a % either side, e.g. %Name%.
 *
 * @return {Object} the completed PDF file
 */

function createPdf() {

  if (TEMPLATE_ID === '') {

    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('TEMPLATE_ID needs to be defined in code.gs')
    return
  }

  // Set up the docs and the spreadsheet access

  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_ID).makeCopy(),
      copyId = copyFile.getId(),
      copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId),
      copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection(),
      activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      numberOfColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn(),
      activeRowIndex = activeSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(),
      activeRow = activeSheet.getRange(activeRowIndex, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      headerRow = activeSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numberOfColumns).getValues(),
      columnIndex = 0

  // Replace the keys with the spreadsheet values

  for (;columnIndex < headerRow[0].length; columnIndex++) {

    copyBody.replaceText('%' + headerRow[0][columnIndex] + '%', 
                         activeRow[0][columnIndex])                         
  }

  // Create the PDF file, rename it if required and delete the doc copy

  copyDoc.saveAndClose()

  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'))  

  if (PDF_FILE_NAME !== '') {

    newFile.setName(PDF_FILE_NAME)
  } 

  copyFile.setTrashed(true)

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('New PDF file created in the root of your Google Drive')

} // createPdf()
```